# Playing ansible task in case of a dict is existing or not

Tags: dictionary, ansible

I'm trying to let ansible play a task in case of that a dict is defined or not.

Im group vars to a host group I define a dict called "files_to_copy_from_nexus" when I need to copy files from nexus for that group.
If the dict is not defined in group vars file Ansible don't need to copy anything.

And this is my main.yml which should include the tasks for copying the files in case of dict existing or not:

```
  - include: copy-lists-for-docker-container.yml
    when: files_to_copy_from_nexus is defined and files_to_copy_from_nexus.keys()|length > 0
```

But when I play the playbook now for a hostgroup which hasn't the dict defined I get a

```
TASK [do-docker-deployment : Copy files from Nexus] ****************************
fatal: [app_without_dict]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dict'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: with_dict expects a dict"}
```

Why does Ansible include the task? Maybe something is wrong in the included play which is this:

```
  - name: Copy files from Nexus
    get_url:
      url: '{{ item.value.source }}'
      dest: '{{ target }}'
      username: '{{ item.value.nexuscopyuser }}'
      password: '{{ item.value.nexuscopypassword }}'
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', files_to_copy_from_nexus) }}"
```

Any good tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Behavior of `include` depends on the context it is running and looking at the error, it appears that in this context `include` is behaving like static `import` since the `when` condition has no problem. Also `include` is probably [going to be deprecated in the near future](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_module.html#notes). Having said that, try using `include_tasks` instead of `include`. This change should solve the problem you are facing.

*Note, similar error may appear if dict isn't defined correctly.*

```yaml
  - include_tasks: copy-lists-for-docker-container.yml
    when: files_to_copy_from_nexus is defined and files_to_copy_from_nexus.keys() | length > 0
```